# can't 'ng-repeat' through javascript array in AngularJS, (by getting a JSON object from Django)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question is not Django related in any way because my Django view which returns a dummy JSON object works perfectly, just thought I would share the Django view which converts a 
`Model.objects.all()` into pure JSON data then returns this pure data for an Angular controller to read and process through an ng-repeat:

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.utils import simplejson

def json(request):

    all_objects = list(Message.objects.all())
    to_json = serializers.serialize('json', all_objects)

    return HttpResponse(to_json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Now on to my question,
I'm not sure if I'm having an Angular issue or pure JavaScript issue. I have an Angular controller called `testjson` which calls that Django view above which then successfully returns a JSON object like this:

```
[
   {
      "pk":1,
      "model":"chatfeed.message",
      "fields":{
         "body":"hey everyone",
         "chat_feed":"Dating",
         "likes":0,
         "author_obj":1,
         "parent_channel":1,
         "pub_date":"2014-03-18T23:29:27Z"
      }
   },
   {
      "pk":2,
      "model":"chatfeed.message",
      "fields":{
         "body":"How's it going?",
         "chat_feed":"Dating",
         "likes":0,
         "author_obj":1,
         "parent_channel":1,
         "pub_date":"2014-03-18T23:32:05Z"
      }
   },
   {
      "pk":3,
      "model":"chatfeed.message",
      "fields":{
         "body":"So what's going on right now",
         "chat_feed":"Events",
         "likes":0,
         "author_obj":1,
         "parent_channel":2,
         "pub_date":"2014-03-18T23:32:33Z"
      }
   },
   {
      "pk":4,
      "model":"chatfeed.message",
      "fields":{
         "body":"Going pretty well actually",
         "chat_feed":"Dating",
         "likes":0,
         "author_obj":1,
         "parent_channel":1,
         "pub_date":"2014-03-18T23:32:55Z"
      }
   }
]
```

And so I would just like to grab the body of a particular `chat_feed` to be printed in Angular JS using Angular's ng-repeat to get something like this if I wanted all chat messages from `chat_feed` "Dating":

```
<div ng-controller="testjson" ng-click="getJSON()">
    <ul ng-model="chatfeed">
        <li ng-repeat="post in chatfeed">{$ post $}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So in order to get the ng-repeat to work, I believe. I would have to loop through the raw JSON object, grab the 'body' string from each index and store them into an array so that's what I did:

```
app.controller("testjson", function($scope, $http)
{
        $scope.getJSON = function()
            {

                var JSONObject = $http.get('http://domfa.de/testjson/').success(function(data)
                {
                    $scope.totalfeed = data.length;

                    chatarray = new Array();
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (data[i].fields.chat_feed == $scope.currentFeed)
                        {
                            chatarray[i] = data[i].fields.chat_feed;        
                        }
                    }

                    console.log(chatarray);
                    $scope.chatfeed = chatarray;

                }); 

            }
});
```

So after all that, my console.log seems to be returning the proper array just fine with the `"body"`s from the correct `chat_feed`. `Console.log()` is doing what I want it to do and the array it prints is properly formatted with perfect syntax, but as for the HTML which calls the `ng-repeat="post in chatfeed"` angular function it doesn't seem to print anything at all unless I physically copy and past the array `console.log()` prints out and replace `ng-model="chatfeed"` with a hardcoded array the console.log() generates for me with no problems using `ng-init="['hows it going?', 'hey everyone']"`.

Comment: You do not need ng-model on the ul. Not sure it is even valid on that element. Inside the <li>, try {{post}}.

Comment: Have you tried placing `chatfeed` on `$scope` before you call `$scope.getJSON = function(){...};`? When you place something on `$scope`, angular places a watcher on it, which will roll changes to that variable into the `$digest` loop. I'm wondering if your ng-repeat doesn't know about `chatfeed` when the view renders and is therefore not doing anything when it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getJSON` to populate `chatfeed` when the div is clicked.  I wasn't able to trigger `getJSON` because I couldn't see where to click.  So, I added some text to the div:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-click="getJSON()">click me!
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in chatfeed">{{ post }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I clicked the div, I got an error message regarding duplicates in `ng-repeat`.  If `currentFeed = 'Dating',` then there are 3 matching chat posts with the 'Dating' `chat_feed`.  To allow for the duplicates, I added a tracking expression:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in chatfeed track by $index">{{ post }}</li>
```

But then, the list only displayed 'Dating' 3 times.  You want the messages to be displayed - not the category.  So, I changed the getJSON to add `body` instead of `chat_feed` to `chatarray`:

```
$scope.chatarray.push($scope.data[i].fields.body)
```

After making this change, the tracking expression is no long necessary because the `body` of each chat is unique.

Here is the plunker demo with the final adjustments: http://plnkr.co/edit/J4PtDpeRHO8TVItUnHJw?p=preview